# Is $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$? For $f(x) = \frac{x^3+x}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Here's my work flow.

---

I've used this graph from Khan Academy, while it's indeterminate at first glance, it seems like we'd be able to find it's limit by factorising.

[image]

---

I also graphed it to see that there's any break in the graph, but can't seem to find a hole/break in the graph that makes is "not continuous", I've thus assumed that it IS continuous.

***MY QUESTION:***
What did I do wrong and can you help me identify/bridge my knowledge gap please?
[image]

---

Here's the original question, which doesn't even mention limit... :

[image]

If I cheated and used Wolfram alpha using limits it shows there's a break in limit, how did they get the graph like that?
[image]

Comment: The correct answer is c) because $f$ has not been defined at $0$.

Comment: The function, unaltered, would require a division by zero at zero. Full stop. That's it.

Comment: Giving a formula to define a function is pretty sloppy if they don't mention the domain. If the function is not defined at $0$ it doesn't even make sense to talk about continuity at $0$. If you do define the function at $0$, it's very easy to make the function continuous at $0$ by defining $f(0)$ as $1$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, none of the given answers is correct: The grouping of words, numbers, and symbols: $$(x^3+x)/x\colon\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R \text{ is continuous at $x=0.$}$$isn't a statement at all, i.e., neither true or false.  No more information needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function to be continuous at $x=a$ the condition is that $$\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = f(a) = \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)$$ In the given case, we can easily see that, $$\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x^3+x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^-}(x^2+1) = 1$$
And, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^3+x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}(x^2+1) = 1$$ Now, if $f(0)$ *were explicitly defined* to be $1$, then the function would be continuous at $x=0$, as many others have pointed out.

In the absence of this definition, however, $$f(0) = \frac{0^3 + 0}{0}$$ which is **undefined**. The cancellation of $x$ in the numerator an denominator can only be done when solving for the limit, and not when finding out the functional value at that point.

Thus, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the condition for continuity of a function  $f(x) $ at a point $c$ is
$$\lim_{x\to c}f (x)=f(c) $$
Here, as you said the left hand side evaluates, by factoring, to $1$. However, the factorisation does work iff $x\neq 0$ (think why?). So, the function $f $ is not defined at $x=0$.
Clearly, as the right hand side is not defined, the condition is false, and therefore $f$ is discontinuous at $0$. The hole arises from the same.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what definitions you're using. For instance, for y=f(x) to be a function it needs to be defined for every x in its domain. In this case the domain hasn't been defined, so it's possible for it to be defined at f(0)=1, or it's possible the domain is R - {0}. Both of which are continuous (and these are the most likely ways to do things). It could also be defined as f(0)=10, which isn't continuous. However it's done, to be a function y=f(x) needs to be defined for every x in its domain.

The next thing that needs defined is the context of "continuity". Are you being asked whether the function is continuous over the Reals? Because it isn't **unless** f(0) is explicitly defined as 1. Or are you being asked if it's continuous over its domain? Because it is, in this case, if it's a function.

Generally, what you're actually being asked with questions like these is - is the domain the Real numbers? If it isn't then there are discontinuities over the Reals somewhere. Your job is to find and understand them.

In this case, we have a division by 0 that's created a removable discontinuity. So we can say that it is discontinuous over the Reals unless we define f(0)=1.

Please note that we can't define our way out of all our problems. Take 1/x, there's no value we can assign f(0) that will make it continuous at 0. Have a think about what makes it different.

Comment: Use MathJax for formatting maths. Use ```$...$```, _e.g._ ```$x^2+3x+\frac{1}{x}$``` for $x^2+3x+\frac1x$. Use ```$\mathbb{R}$``` for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For $\{$ and $\}$, use ```\{``` and ```\}```. These might seem just too weird, but for mathematical typesetting, this becomes good so that equations become more readable.

Comment: I take your point and its a good one. The next time I have access to a keyboard I'll give it a go. If some of the common markup was exposed in a WYSIWYG editor it would make things a lot easier for me the 99% of the time I'm away from a computer lol

Comment: I guess you can use Desktop site on your mobile.